# How do I sort posts by category per user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and I've been working on an app where collectors of Funko pops can login and log the Funko pops they have. It's very simple, and there are only a few fields for entering information about the funkos themselves; Title, description and category along with the ability to upload an image of the funko so the users home screen displays almost like a shelf, with all their funkos on.

ANYWAY. I have functionality built in, allowing users to sort their home screen by category, so if a user clicks the dropdown and selects "Marvel" then they should see all Marvel funko pops they have. If they have no Funkos with a category of "Marvel" then a message appears saying there are no funkos in this category. This functionality works perfectly, however when I create a new user and sign in, and sort by category, it shows all of the Funkos in the selected category **but for all users**.

I want to be able to display the funkos by category, on a per user basis, so all funkos the user has entered should be sortable using the categories dropdown.

Here is code for the main controller:

```
class FunkosController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_funko, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    if user_signed_in? && params[:category].blank?
        @funkos = Funko.where(:user_id => current_user.id).all.order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:category].present?
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id                    
        @funkos = Funko.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    else
    end
end

def show
end

def new
    @funko = current_user.funko.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
end

def create
    @funko = current_user.funko.build(funko_params)
    @funko.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @funko.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
end

def update
    @funko.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @funko.update(funko_params)
        redirect_to funko_path(@funko)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @funko.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private
    def funko_params
        params.require(:funko).permit(:title, :description, :category_id, :funko_img)
    end

    def find_funko
        @funko = Funko.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Hopefully my first post/question on here is clear and concise enough to get the answer I'm looking for!

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I create a new user and sign in, and sort by category, it
>   shows all of the Funkos in the selected category but for all users.

The problem lies here

```
@funkos = Funko.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
```

You are not fetching `funkos` per user if `params[:category]` is present. Add that, and you are good to go

```
@funkos = Funko.where(:category_id => @category_id, :user_id => current_user.id).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!